# Is there an integer solution to $x^2+1978=y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Is there an integer solution to $x^2+1978=y^2$?

Don't know really how to approach this.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$$(y+x)(y-x)=1978\equiv2\pmod4$$

But $y+x+(y-x)=2y$ or $y+x-(y-x)=2x$ is even  $\implies y\pm x$ have the same parity

Comment: How does this help me?

Comment: @user114138, If $y-x$ is even, so will be $y+x\implies y^2-x^2$ will be divisible by $4$  What if $y-x$ is odd?

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No. Squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$, but $1978 \equiv 2 \mod 4$.

Comment: You meant the difference of 2 squares?

Comment: No, I meant squares. Difference of 2 squares can therefore be 1-1=0-0=0, 1-0=1 or 0-1=-1=3, but never 2.

Answer (score 2):

$(y+x)(y−x)=1978$

$1978=2\times23\times43$

is (i) $46\times43=1978$ or;
   (ii)$23\times86=1978$

Case(i)
      $$x+y=46$$
      $$y-x=43$$
      $$\Longrightarrow x=1.5 \wedge y=44.5$$
Case (ii)
      $$x+y=86$$
      $$y-x=23$$
      $$\Longrightarrow x=31.5 \wedge y=54.5$$

Which means the equation have no integer solution

Comment: What about case (iii) $2\times989=1978$?

Comment: Yeah i forgot the third case, which will give the following results x=493.5 & y=495.5 so no integer value..

Answer (score 1):

An integer number $n$ is represented by the quadratic form $x^2-y^2$ iff $n\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, since
$$ x^2-y^2 = n $$
is equivalent to:
$$ (x-y)(x+y)=n, $$
that can be read as "$n$ has two complementary divisors $d,\frac{n}{d}$ with the same parity".